# Blazor web assembly localized resource naming

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am noticing strange behavior with Blazor localization when using IStringLocalizer, it seems that in web assembly host the resource names needs to be in simple format (as noted in docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-8.0#example-of-localized-resources)) without region name, for example en-US would need to be named en. The thing is that this behavior is different in different hosting environments, for example same code running in desktop application would look for en-US resource instead.
This adds an complexity where I would need to add two set of resources for each language in order for the localization to work in different environments.

Honestly I am not even sure that in the end my application would actually need to use region names but still the question is why and is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: I just spun up a WASM app. `App.resx`, `App.en.resx`, `App.en-AU.resx`. The behaviour was as expected. If I deleted `App.en-AU.resx` it fell back to `App.en.resx` If I deleted that it fell back to `App.resx`.